# Is it possible to mute a specific person in Steam chat?

Tags: steam

When in a multi-user steam chat room, is it possible to mute a specific person, ideally without blocking other communication from them? I'm playing in the same physical room as the person and I'd like us both to be able to chat without having to hear each other twice.

Comment: What do you mean "same room", if you open a chat window with someone on steam you dont have vocal communication still you can chat to each other.

Comment: I think he's talking about being in the same physical room as someone in his group chat, and hearing the same person twice because of it.

Comment: I meant the same physical room. Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: I suspect there would be a mute button near their avatar in the chat room. If no option exists then you could always try wearing earmuffs over your headphones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no way to mute a specific user in a Steam group call.** Even blocking the user on Steam will not mute the user in the call. The only way to prevent hearing the user is to mute the whole call or leave it.